# Optimizar tablas de Mysql InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

Tengo una base de datos de MySQL de casi 15 GB con muchas tablas, algunas de ellas gigantescas.

Quería hacer la tarea de optimización pero al ser `INNODB` no es posible.

Por lo que me han contado esta base de datos lleva funcionando desde el año 2000 y nunca se le ha hecho ninguna tarea de mantenimiento.

¿Cuál es la mejor forma que conocéis para realizar el optimice a este tipo de base de datos?

Answer (score 1):

En [MySQL 5.7 sí se puede optimizar tablas InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html)

> OPTIMIZE TABLE works for InnoDB, MyISAM, and ARCHIVE tables. OPTIMIZE
>   TABLE is also supported for dynamic columns of in-memory NDB tables.
>   It does not work for fixed-width columns of in-memory tables, nor does
>   it work for Disk Data tables.

Si estás corriendo en un servidor con una versión antigua, lo recomendable sería:

1. Sacar un dump completo de la base de datos
2. Levantar un servidor con MySQL 5.7 y activar la opción [innodb_file_per_table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) (esto ayuda mucho para futuras optimizaciones)
3. Cargar el dump
4. Apuntar la aplicación a la nueva DB

Sacando el dump y cargándolo en la nueva DB de por sí te dejará las tablas optimizadas, pero para futuras optimizaciones te convendrá estar corriendo en 5.7 y tener cada tabla en su propio archivo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias....lo voy a probar.... de momento haré lo de crear una db nueva y cargar el dump, será largo pero bueno... y ya voy preparando lo de actualizar el motor MYSQL 5.7...